# ¿Como quitar el siguiente error de mi datetime picker en cakephp 3?

Tags: datetime, cakephp

[image: Error en el datetime picker al momento de agregar una hora]

Hola buen día, disculpen tengo este problema en mi proyecto. Sucede que agregue un datetime picker y funciona pero el problema esta cuando agrego la hora el formulario se queda en este estado. 
 aqui les presento mi código del **add**:

```
<div id="datetimepicker" class="input-append date  col-xs-12 col-md-8">
<?php echo $this->Form->control('fecha_presentacion', ['label'=>'Fecha y    hora de presentación: ', 'empty' => true, 'data-format' => 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss', 'type' => 'text']);  ?>   
  <span class="add-on">
    <i data-time-icon="icon-time" data-date-icon="icon-calendar"></i>
  </span>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js">
</script> 
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.2.2/js/bootstrap.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
 src="http://tarruda.github.com/bootstrap-datetimepicker/assets/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.pt-BR.js">
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss',
    language: 'es'
  });
</script>
```

Espero su respuesta me ayudaría bastante, gracias.

Answer (score 3):

**Saludos**

En la página del componente [bootstrap-datetimepicker](https://github.com/AuspeXeu/bootstrap-datetimepicker) da vistazo a **format** los minutos son *ii* no *mm*.